# CRM 2011 OnPremise - Permissions for Notes/Annotations

Tags: permissions, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Have a seemingly contradictory issue with Notes/Annotations on Contacts/Accounts.

This is the permissions for the Note entity for a custom role we have defined:

[image]

Summary:

- Individual Create
- Organisational Read
- Individual write
- None for delete
- BU Append
- BU Append To
- BU Assign
- None for share

I go to the account screen and as expected, I **cannot** amend another user's note.

I go to the contact screen and I **can** amend another user's note.

Is there some aspect of the permissions I am missing?

Comment: Would love to know how this is off topic - very strange.

Comment: I'm actually partly the culprit here. I upvoted it as a question, but I flagged it as off topic because it seems better suited for the MSDN forums or a potential [CRM stackexchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6200/microsoft-dynamics-crm) site as it's currently worded.

Answer (score 0):

What are the "Append To" privileges in this role for the Contact and Account? Since you're trying to Append the Annotation TO the Contact and Account...

Otherwise saying: the "Append" priviliges for the Annotation go hand-in-hand with the "Append To" priviliges for the entity you'd want to add the Annotation to, like the Contact or Account.

Comment: Both are set to BU - however there is no issue with creating the notes (which is when the append/append to permissions apply I think), the issue is with the discrepancy on updating.

Comment: OK, I did misread that part. Only other thing that comes to mind is whether the user you are testing with really only is in this custom role you described above.